Replace "_" with " " of all files and directories within a parent directory - Powershell
I have a parent directory that contains many sub directories. I want to replace the underscore with a space in all directories and files within each directory. What's the best / quickest way to achieve this using Powershell?
E.g.
Current:

folder_1
-- file_1.mp4
-- file_1.srt
-- file_1.vtt
folder_2
-- file_2.mp4
-- file_2.srt
-- file_2.vtt
folder_3
-- file_3.mp4
-- file_3.srt
file_3.vtt

Wanted:

folder 1
-- file 1.mp4
-- file 1.srt
-- file 1.vtt
folder 2
-- file 2.mp4
-- file 2.srt
-- file 2.vtt
folder 3
-- file 3.mp4
-- file 3.srt
-- file 3.vtt

Thanks in advance!
get-childitem *.* | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_", " ") }

get-childitem -recurse | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.name.replace("_"," ") }

I have tried these but they only half do what I want.

what do you mean with "half"? Also you can pipe Get-ChildItem directly to Rename-Item.

I tried googling this for a long time and I could only find code that would do part of what I wanted. The first one will rename all files within a directory, however when i try running it on the parent directory it does nothing. The second one will rename all the directories, but it will not rename the files within that directory.

Here. I split everything in 3 operations, because it's better to rename the files first and the directories second, so to not use multiple Get-ChildItem I got them all in a variable at the start.
# Get all directories and subdirectories having a Underscore(_) in their Name.   
$DirectoryList = Get-ChildItem -Path $BasePath -Recurse | 
    Where-Object -Property BaseName -Match '_'

#Rename all files  
$DirectoryList | Where-Object { $_.gettype().name -eq 'FileInfo' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('_', ' ') }

# Rename all directories
$DirectoryList | Where-Object { $_.gettype().name -eq 'DirectoryInfo' } |    
    # Added sort so to rename the directory recursively starting from the
    # deepest to avoid errors.  
    Sort-Object -Descending { $_.FullName.split([io.path]::DirectorySeparatorChar).count } |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('_', ' ') }


You bloody legend! That worked perfectly. Many thanks my friend. Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

I added a Sort-Object to the answer so to make sure the deepest directories get renamed first, to avoid "Directory A_B\B_C doesn't exist"(because A_B was renamed to "A B" first) scenarios. I have no doubt there are better methods, but this also did seem a good way to show some non-intuitive working
